# Python list function in pandas data frame

Tags: python, list

Tried to change the index of the `DataFrame` using `list()` but ends in error.

[image]

created a new data frame with a 20x dataset and tried to change the index values to strings of `a`, `b` like this.

resulting in

`TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: Did you overwrite list with a custom type?

Comment: or a local `list` object?

Comment: You are passing a list inside list. Just write index=list('abcde')

Comment: @HimanshuPanwar That would throw the same error if there exists a variable called `list` which is not callable

Comment: If you could please share your code as text, not a screenshot. You can copy/paste and then highlight what was pasted and click the `{}` button in the editor to preserve line-feeds and white space.

Comment: As other folks are suggesting, you likely did something in a cell above to overwrite the built-in `list` object with something else entirely. Your code that you are sharing with us would, otherwise, work.